# How do I pass a keyword pair as an argument to a module in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-datetime

Below is a function that searches a list of dates and returns the number of occurrences on a specified date. I can pass in the number of days to `relativedelta(days=x)` through the call `zettel(1)` but I'd also like to pass in a number of years (i.e. `relativedelta(years=x)`).

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

notelist = ['20211204', '20201205', '20191205', '20181205']


def zettel(x):
    ''' Returns the number of zettel created on this day 'x' years ago.'''
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - relativedelta(days=x)
    note_count = 0
    for uuid in notelist:
        if uuid == note_uuid.strftime('%Y%m%d'):
            note_count += 1
    return [x, note_count, note_uuid.strftime('%Y%m%d')]


print(f'[{zettel(1)[1]} new zettel yesterday.') 

print(zettel(1))
```

I've tried passing in `days`, `years` and the number with

```
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - relativedelta(y=x)
```

But I get
`NameError: name 'years' is not defined`
When I call the function with
`print(f'[{zettel(years, 1)[1]})`

I've tried passing the whole argument `days=1` and `year=1` with

```
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - relativedelta(x)
```

But I get
`TypeError: zettel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'years'`
When I call the function with
`print(f'[{zettel(years=1)[1]})`

How can I pass the keyword "days" and "years" to the function relativedelta? Is this possible?

This code works but I'd like to expand it so it will be useful to count a different number of days or years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few different ways you could achieve this.

**Option 1:** Pass in "days" and "years directly. Example call: `zettel(years=1)`.

```
def zettel(years=0, days=0):
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=years, days=days)
    ...
```

**Option 2:** Pass relativedelta directly. Example call: `zettel(relativedelta(years=1))`.

```
def zettel(lookback):
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - lookback
    ...
```

**Option 3:** Pass keyword arguments. Example call: `zettel(years=1)`.

```
def zettel(**lookback):
    note_uuid = datetime.now() - relativedelta(**lookback)
    ...
```